# Getting data from API using json and requests module

Tags: json

Hi I am trying to get the data in the attached image using python using json & requests module.

If I use the following link the code works:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR

However when I use the desired path as in the attached image I get the following error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value`

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Code is below:

`import json
import requests`

`url = "https://dpssdata.coherent.com/rest.aspx?products&version=2&breaks=1.json"
r = requests.get(url)`

`json_data = r.json()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting redirected to login.

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
>>> r
<Response [302]>
>>> r.text
'<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>\r\n<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://sts.coherent.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&amp;wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fdpssdata.coherent.com%2f&amp;wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252frest.aspx%253fproducts%2526version%253d2%2526breaks%253d1.json&amp;wct=2018-06-23T05%3a43%3a37Z">here</a>.</h2>\r\n</body></html>\r\n'
```

Presumably you have logged in in your browser. So you'll need to securely store the login token and use that in your auth header. It looks like the site supports X.509 Certificates also which would probably be the way to go for automated access.

Comment: Hi Luke, Which works for you? The: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR works for me too. It’s the rest.aspx address as in the attached image that doesn’t work...

Comment: Also - get a good response code 200 I just can’t seem to access the data...

Comment: Oh I see. The second one is an authenticated URL. If you instead do

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False) you can see that you're getting redirected to login. I assume you're logged in in your browser.